# How to loop until user input N in C

Tags: c, loops, input, while-loop, scanf

I'm a beginner in C program, and I'm trying to make a restaurant order menu. 
I start with user input "Y" to start order.
Then I want the program to keep taking orders until user input "N" to stop.
When input "N", the total sales will printed. 
But I cannot do the looping, would you mind to help me? Thank you. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int code;
float totalPrice=0, totalSales = 0 ;
char choice, choice1;

printf("Welcome to Deli Sandwich! Enter Y to start your order!\n");
scanf("%c", &choice);

while(choice=='Y'|| choice=='y')
{
    printf("\n____________________________SANDWICH FILLING______________________________\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Menu \t\t Code \t\t Price\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Egg \t\t 1 \t\t RM 1.00\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Tuna \t\t 2 \t\t RM 2.00\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Seafood \t 3 \t\t RM 3.00\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Chicken Ham \t 4 \t\t RM 2.50\n");

    printf("\nSandwich Filling code: ");
    scanf("%d", &code);

    switch(code)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Egg is picked.\n");
        totalPrice+= 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Tuna is picked.\n");
        totalPrice+= 2;
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Seafood is picked.\n");
        totalPrice+= 3;
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Chicken Ham is picked.\n");
        totalPrice+= 2.50;
        break;
    default :
        printf("invalid code.");

    }

    printf("\n_____________________________SANDWICH TYPE________________________________\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Menu \t\t Code \t\t Price\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Half \t\t 1 \t\t RM 3.00\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Whole \t\t 2 \t\t RM 5.00\n");

    printf("\nSandwich Type code: ");
    scanf("%d", &code);

    switch(code)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Half is picked.\n");
        totalPrice+= 3;
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Whole is picked.\n");
        totalPrice+= 5;
        break;
    default :
        printf("invalid code.");

    }

    printf("\nThe total price is RM%.2f.\n", totalPrice);
    printf("Thank You. Please come again!\n");

    totalSales+= totalPrice;

    printf("\nWelcome to Deli Sandwich! Enter Y to start your order!\n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

}

printf("\nThe total sales is RM%.2f.\n", totalSales);

return 0;
```

}

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%c", &choice);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &choice); // note the space before %c
```

This is done to discard all white-space characters like `\n` and spaces from the `stdin`.

When you enter data for a `scanf`,you enter some data and press the <kbd>enter key</kbd>. `scanf` consumes the data entered and leaves the `\n`(<kbd>enter key</kbd>) in the input buffer(`stdin`). When `scanf` with a `%c` is called the next time, it will take the `\n` as input(left over by the previous `scanf`) and will not wait for further input.

In your code,

```
scanf("%c", &choice);
```

before the `while` loop consumes the character you entered and leaves the `\n` in the `stdin`. As for why

```
scanf("%d", &code);
```

waits for input is that the `%d` format specifier skips white-space characters while `%c` does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

Ignore the newline character at the end of the input by placing a space before `%c`

Answer (score 0):

simple add the space before %c

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press after providing the input is stored into the input buffer `stdin` and considered a *valid* input for `%c` format specifier for the recurring `scanf()`s. To avoid *scanning* the stored `\n`, you need to change your code like

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
      ^
      |
```

This leading space indicates to *ignore* any leading whitespace or whitespace-like characters (including `\n`) and *scan* the first non-whitespace character. [In your case `y`/ `Y`/ `n`...]